# The learning of Bris Milah

Tags: jewish-books, brit-milah

I am interested to learn the halachos of Hilchos Milah in a more practical manner.

Are there any books that one can recommend? Hebrew or English works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you mean the laws of performing the mila (for a mohel) or the general laws of mila (e.g., for a new father). In the latter case, I can recommend two books I really liked:

- the classic artscroll "[Bris Milah / Circumcision](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899061979.html)"
- a sefer in Hebrew called Brit Its'hak which covers the relevant halachot as well as the texts typically recited the night before the brit mila (I read it in French/Hebrew but understand it is a translation of the original Hebrew version)